# Strange behaviour of vector::size() with if condition

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet:

```
cout << indexCoveredA[a.size()-1] << " "<< b.size()-1 << endl;
if (indexCoveredA[a.size()-1] < (b.size() - 1) ) {
  cout << "entered";
}
```

Where `a`, `b`, `indexCoveredA` and `indexCoveredB` are `std::vector<int>`.

When I run this code, the console prints:

```
-1 4
```

This means that in the if condition, LHS is less than RHS. However "entered" is not printed, which means that the if condition is evaluated to be false.

Now if I change the condition to `(indexCoveredA[a.size()-1] + 1 < b.size() )`, then "entered" is printed in the console.

I have tried this out with MSVC and minGW compilers. I am not able to understand why this is so.

Can someone please explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `indexCoveredA[]` is `int`, but the type of `b.size()` is an unsigned type (whatever `size_t` is, likely either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`).

As a result, this comparison gets performed as an unsigned comparison.  As an unsigned number, `-1` looks much larger than `4`.

You can try this example to demonstrate to yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = -1;
    unsigned u = 4;

    if (i < u)
    {
        std::cout << "less" << std::endl;
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "not less" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This prints `not less`.

If I compile with G++ and warnings enabled, I get the following warning that hints at the problem:

```
x.c: In function ‘int main()’:
x.c:8: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

You might turn warnings on for your compiler.